# How to sum the grouping results of a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have this code and I need to sum the variable category which the count value, I'm trying this. Without any additional library

```js
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import base64
```

```js
dfex2 = pd.DataFrame({'var': ["A", "A", "B", "A","C"], 'count': [1,2,5,1,0]})
dfex2.groupby(['var','count'])['count'].count()
```

And i'm getting this result.

```
var  count
A    1        2
     2        1
B    5        1
C    0        1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

but I need something like this:

```
var  result
A    4
B    5
C    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you sum instead ?

```
dfex2.groupby(['var'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

True, as the comment said, there is no much explanation:

- We group by 'var', we consider the 'count' column for which we sum the values, then reset the index so we get a df instead of a series

Comment: This should be a comment, please don't post answers with little to no information or explanations